# Why are my QuickForm checkboxes always ticked, in postProcess()?

Tags: quickform

I'm trying to build a form using QuickForm checkboxes. Here's what should happen:

1. The form displays a bunch of checkboxes. These are ticked or unticked according to a load of API calls in buildQuickForm(). If ticked, this is set using setChecked->true.
2. The user then ticks or unticks appropriately, and postProcess() handles the changes.

Except, the form data received by postProcess() is wrong: if a checkbox is set as ticked using setChecked->true, it always comes through as ticked, even if the user unticked it.

I assume I'm not understanding Civi's [QuickForm process](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC42/QuickForm+Reference) properly. Could setChecked->true be kicking in after the form is submitted? During validation, or something?

Any advice appreciated...

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. Do the setting in setDefaultValues() instead of buildQuickForm().
2. I find the "form data received by postProcess" often contains duplicates and miscellaneous other stuff and I'm sometimes not sure what to look at but usually use $this->_submitValues for visible fields. What are you examining?

Comment: that did it - thanks! I get the values from $this->controller->exportValues($this->_name), which I think I just ripped from the wiki somewhere. Seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1):

I always use the setDefaultValues() to add values to my form fields and boxes, like so:

```
function setDefaultValues() {
    $defaults = array();
    foreach ($this->_monthlyPattern as $number => $percentage) {
      $defaults['month'.$number] = $percentage;
    }
    return $defaults;
  }
```